# Iterate an array with content but with length 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I've got a list of calls with phone numbers and numbers of times that I called these numbers.
Every time I call I do something like this:

```
const pos = '.' + this.number; // avoid arrays large as a mobile number but keeping the number for indexing

    if (typeof(this.list[pos]) === 'undefined') {
      this.list[pos] = 1;
    } else {
      this.list[pos] = this.list[pos] + 1;
    }
```

So I can get how many times did I call that number doing easily something like `this.list[number]`.

The problem comes when I want to iterate this array:

```
<div *ngFor="let calls of callsListProvider.list">{{calls}}</div>
```

The length of the array is always 0 because I didn't push the content.

I don't want to use objects. Is this possible to iterate and also get the number (the index) as well?

Comment: What is purpose of `'.'` at `const pos = '.' + this.number`? `this.list[pos] = this.list[pos] + 1` concatenates a string? Have you tried using `for..in` loop instead of `for..of` loop?

Comment: If you don't add any character, being a phone number the array will be as big as the phone number is. So if you only have the number 075645, you will have 75644 empty positions but the length will be 075645

Answer (score 1):

If `this.list` is an `Array` having property names set to values other than indexes you can substitute using `for..in` loop for `for..of` loop.

```js
let arr = [];
arr["a"] = 1;
arr["b"] = 2;

for (let prop of arr) {
  console.log("for..of loop", prop);
}

for (let prop in arr) {
  console.log("for..in loop", prop);
}
```

Comment: perfect, that works. I'll find the way to translate it to Angular

Comment: @DanielRodriguez See [Difference between for...of and for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Difference_between_for...of_and_for...in)